# Simple mortgage portfolio amortization

Tags: portfolio-theory

I have a large residential mortgage portfolio that has fixed and arm mortgages. I want to roughly calculate the amortization of the arm portfolio by year without delving into loan by loan calculations. Would that be possible to go by using weighted average margins, maturities, some assumptions on prepayment rate and index rate?